# Installing AzureADPreview Powershell module fails in docker image

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-code, azure-powershell

I'm trying to install / use the AzureADPreview powershell module to automate the creation of a policy.

I am using the following Dockerfile for my devcontainer in VSCode:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell:latest
```

I'd like to install the module in this container and do all my dev work inside.

Problem is I can't seem to get the module installed in the container.

I am able to do this on my HOST machine (windows box):

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\src\test> Get-Module azureadpreview -ListAvailable

    Directory: C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Binary     2.0.2.149             AzureADPreview                      Desk

PS C:\Users\me\Documents\src\test> Import-Module AzureADPreview -RequiredVersion 2.0.2.149
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\src\test> Get-Command -Module AzureADPreview -Name Get-AzureADPo*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-AzureADPolicy                                  2.0.2.149  AzureADPreview
Cmdlet          Get-AzureADPolicyAppliedObject                     2.0.2.149  AzureADPreview

PS C:\Users\me\Documents\src\test> New-AzureADPolicy

cmdlet New-AzureADPolicy at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Definition[0]:
```

When i try the same commands in the vscode container, I get this error:

```
PS /workspaces/test>  Install-Module AzureADPreview
PS /workspaces/test> Get-Module azureadpreview -ListAvailable               

    Directory: /root/.local/share/powershell/Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Binary     2.0.2.149             AzureADPreview                      Desk      


PS /workspaces/test> Import-Module AzureADPreview -RequiredVersion 2.0.2.149
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**EDIT 1**

```
root@662a90ff1b93:/workspaces/test# pwsh
PowerShell 7.2.4
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.
    
PS /workspaces/test> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

PS /workspaces/test> Register-PackageSource -Trusted -ProviderName 'PowerShellGet' -Name 'Posh Test Gallery' -Location 'https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2'
Register-PackageSource: The specified Uri 'https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2' for parameter 'Location' is an invalid Web Uri. Please ensure that it meets the Web Uri requirements.
```

Here's the version table:

```
PS /workspaces/test> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.4
OS                             Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

And here's the dockerfile that creates this container I'm in:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

> Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

PowerShell cloudshell/mac runs with few limitations when executing AzureAD modules

Currently, `AzureAD.Standard.Preview`, a preview version of .NET Standard-based, module is available. This module provides the same functionality as `AzureAD` that overrides the default `Connect-AzureAD` so that it uses the custom authentication mechanism CloudShell/Mac uses to avoid you having to re-enter credentials.

For Workaround you can use the below command to install the `AzureADStandardPreview` module.

This Partially should works.

```
Register-PackageSource -Trusted -ProviderName 'PowerShellGet' -Name 'Posh Test Gallery' -Location https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2/'
Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
import-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
```

**Note : Make sure you got powershell 7.1.5/`Upgraded version` installed on your mac**

**Another more Important things to notice here is, from [this PowerShell forums thread](https://forums.powershell.org/t/azuread-module-installed-on-mac-but-connect-azuread-is-not-recognized/16062/7)**:

> The AzureAD module won’t be supported on PowerShell Core. Try using
> the Microsoft Graph SDK. It is and will be supported cross-platform.
>
> The legacy Graph APIs are being retired on 30th June 2022 and while
> Microsoft seem determined to keep exactly what’s going to happen to
> the AzureAD and MSOL modules a secret, some functionality (licensing)
> will definitely stop working when the APIs are retired in favour of
> Microsoft Graph. The broad consensus is that everyone should be
> working to upgrade their scripts and modules to use the Microsoft
> Graph SDK instead of the AzureAD and MSOL modules.

Comment: Sorry, the question is more about docker container than mac specific.  I'm trying to install this powershell module & run the commands in a container so I don't clutter up my environment.  I just tried your code in the container it fails.  Please see edit 1

Comment: also, as far as using Graph to do this, are you sure it's an option?  this is the article I was referring to and it doesn't list Graph:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/allow-deny-list

Comment: if you already install powershell **PSGallery** then just try to run  only **Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview** and then
**import-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview**